# SwiftUI Map rotates after user interaction

Tags: swift, swiftui

(XCode 15 Beta 4, IOS 17 beta 4)

I have this SwiftUI Map.

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var position: MapCameraPosition = .userLocation(followsHeading: true, fallback: .automatic)

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Map(position: $position)
        }
        .mapControls {
            MapUserLocationButton()
            MapScaleView()
        }
    }
}
```

When I touch location button to center map on user, with heading, then zoom in or out without rotating or panning, the map immediately rotates counter-clockwise around the user's potition.

You can see this in the screen recording.  Any suggestions for troubleshooting, or known reasons for this?

[image: Map issue]

Answer (score 0):

Issue is not present in latest releases of Xcode/iOS beta (5, 6).